# Adding pixels in css

Tags: html, css

is there any ways to make class add pixels to element?
For example:

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red
}

.wider {
  width: calc(width + 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block wider"></div>
```

So, .wider makes .block elements wider on 100px, how do I do that in the right way?

Comment: This will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Nested_calc()_with_CSS_Variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could attempt using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and the `var()` function.
By defining an `--width` variable in your `.block` selector then setting the width attribute of the `.wider` selector to be `calc(var(--width) + 100px`, you can achieve a class that makes the box wider. Note that in order for this to work properly you have to add an additional `--width` attribute to every css selector that changes the width.

```css
div {
    width: var(--width, 100%);
}
.block {
  height: 100px;
  --width: 100px;
  background-color: red
}
.wideblock {
  height: 100px;
  --width: 200px;
  background-color: blue
}

.wider {
  width: calc(var(--width) + 100px);
}
```

```html
<p>Div with just block:</p>
<div class="block"></div>
<p>Div with block and wider:</p>
<div class="block wider"></div>
<p>Div with wideblock:</p>
<div class="wideblock"></div>
<p>Div with wideblock and wider:</p>
<div class="wideblock wider"></div>
```

EDIT: added `width: --width` to all divs at the request of [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)

Comment: to make this more accurate, even the original width should use the variable

Comment: I believe I have fixed it

Comment: you didn't get me, the width inside the div should be defined by the variable ... making the width:200px and then defining the variable isn't flexible, you are obliged to change both. but defining the variable and using it inside the width will make you change only the variable

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, I believe I have fixed it now